# Can I use a light bulb dimmer to control an AC axial fan?

Tags: mains, fan, dimmer

I have multiple AC axial fan that I need to slow down. Model number is ACI4420HH from ebm-papst. https://www.ebmpapst.com/de/en/products/compact-fans/axial-compact-fans/p/ACI4420HH.html

They run on 230V AC from mains.

Is it possible to just buy a light bulb dimmer switch and slow them down this way?
Would this be dangerous or cause the fans to malfunction?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer directly. I'm sure they will be happy to answer.

Comment: In my experience this does not work and is dangerous for the fan motor. Wrong TRIAC ignition timing can produce DC currents in the motor coil.

Answer (score 1):

The [datasheet](https://img.ebmpapst.com/products/datasheets/EC-axial-fan-ACI4420HH-ENU.pdf) for this fan indicates that it has "Converter electronics and fan electronics fully integrated", so it may actually have a BLDC motor and speed regulation over its specified voltage range of 195-265 VAC. If that is the case, varying the applied voltage with a TRIAC lamp dimmer (or any other means) will have little effect on speed. Lamp dimmers usually won't work well on fan motors (usually shaded pole). You might safely try adjusting voltage using a Variac to see if speed changes, but I would advise against using a lamp dimmer. A speed adjuster designed for ceiling fans should be safe to try.